# add custom tags for custom post type in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, tags

I have many custom post type and I want two of them to be relate by tags. These tags are only useable to these two custom post type only.

like I have two custom post type

```
1. books
2. writer
```

and I want these two post type have custom tag which only usable to these two post type.

How can I do that.

I try with Custom Taxonomies but didn't success.

appreciate quick help.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already pointed out in your question, custom taxonomies are the way to go here. For this taxonomy to behave like the build in taxonomy `post_tag`, you need to set the `hierarchical` parameter to `false`.

To make these taxonomy available to only your two specific post types, you need to specifiy this when registering your taxonomy.

Example

```
register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy_name', array( 'post_type_1', 'post_type_2' ), $args );
```

The codex ([`register_taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)) have a lot of good examples how to register a custom taxonomy. If you still get stuck after this, you should update your question with your code and exact details where you are stuck